# Google Search Parameter Question

Tags: google, google-search, google-search-api, google-local-search

I've been trying to determine different parameters used by Google in their search queries.  In particular, the usg parameter is what is giving me troubles.  Here is an example value given for it, which is from an actual Google query: usg=0_zDqudnCN52ATGjAl3tignXNtBo4%3D

Does anyone know what it could be for / recognize it?

I've done a bit of digging, but haven't found any confirmation as to what it could be.  Here is the link that I took a look at:
http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3892573.htm

Answer (score 1):

This page suggests it could be some form of hash of the URL: http://drupal.org/node/606328#comment-2945348

It's possibly some kind of security thing, just used privately by Google.